# Busque el archivo más pequeño y el más grande en cmd y copie la ruta en una variable

Tags: variables, cmd, batch, rutas, set

He querido hacer un .bat que contenga una cadena de procesos que se encargara de buscar una serie de archivos con nombres aleatorios. Pero cada archivo tiene información especifica, por lo que debo seleccionar la correcta.

Lo he hecho con **forfiles** y hasta hora asi me ha quedado

> Buscar igual o mayor(grande)= `forfiles /S /M * /C "cmd /c if @fsize GEQ 20000000 echo @path`

> Buscar igual o menor(pequeño)= `forfiles /S /M * /C "cmd /c if @fsize LEQ 500000 echo @path`

[Esto lo conseguí gracias al comentario de este usuario en otra pregunta similar (ingles)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47385593/14797271)

> ```
> Operator | Description
> EQU      | equal to
> NEQ      | not equal to
> LSS      | less than
> LEQ      | less than or equal to
> GTR      | greater than
> GEQ      | greater than or equal to
> ```

Para almacenar en variables las ruta completa del archivo, use el comando `set`. Aunque tuve problemas almacenando lo que contenía `@path` porque no lo almacenaba, así que me toco crear dos archivos de texto que en su interior contendría la ruta completa del archivo y leerlo con el `/p` para almacenarlo en una variable

Mas o menos asi me quedo:

```
echo off
forfiles /P "%temp%\folder" /M * /C "cmd /c if @fsize GEQ 20000000 echo @path > "%temp%\largefiles.txt"
set /p largefiles=<"%temp%\largefiles.txt"
forfiles /P "%temp%\folder" /M * /C "cmd /c if @fsize LEQ 500000 echo @path > "%temp%\smalledfiles.txt"
set /p smalledfiles=<"%temp%\smalledfiles.txt"
echo file larger is %largefiles%
echo file smalled is %smalledfiles%

pause
```

[Esta información la obtuve de aquí](https://sodocumentation.net/es/batch-file/topic/3528/variables-en-archivos-por-lotes)

Hasta ahí todo correcto. Solo tengo que llamar `%largefiles%` y `%smalledfiles%` cada vez que buscar la ruta de esos archivos.

Quizás no sea la mejor forma, lo se, y de pronto **forfile** sea obsoleto y exista mejores métodos, no estoy seguro. Pero espero alguien pueda mejorar esto o compartir otros métodos usando `file` and `for`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que leas las respuestas a esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359820/how-to-set-commands-output-as-a-variable-in-a-batch-file) sobre cómo insertar el output de los comandos en variables ya que `set` no es lo más adecuado para eso. De esta manera puedes deshacerte de los archivos de texto que generas.

Ahí se recomienda este código para hacerlo:

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`tu_comando`) DO (
SET largefiles=%%F
)
```

Comment: Excelente. Gracias por tu aporte.